# Why does current subLocality not always pop up when using subLocality with reverseGeocodeLocation

Tags: ios, swift

Im creating an app that tells the user what their closest address is. There seams to be a problem where the `subLocality` is almost always not available. I believe the `subLocality` is basically the city you are in and I've seen examples of this where is shows up just fine. Whats the problem? Here is my code:

```
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation)
    { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil
        {
            println(error)
        }
        else
        {
            let pm = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark)

            var subThoroughtare:String = ""
            var thoroughfare:String = ""
            var subLocality:String = ""
            var subAdministrativeArea:String = ""
            var postalCode:String = ""
            var country:String = ""

            if pm.subThoroughfare != nil {subThoroughtare = pm.subThoroughfare!}
            if pm.thoroughfare != nil {thoroughfare = pm.thoroughfare!}
            if pm.subLocality != nil {subLocality = pm.subLocality!}
            if pm.subAdministrativeArea != nil {subAdministrativeArea = pm.subAdministrativeArea!}
            if pm.postalCode != nil {postalCode = pm.postalCode!}
            if pm.country != nil {country = pm.country!}
            self.addressLabel.text = "\(subThoroughtare) \(thoroughfare) \n \(subLocality) \n \(postalCode) \n \(country)"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to get the city use **locality** instead

```
var locality: String! { get } // city, eg. Cupertino
```

The difference is that **subLocality** is actually the neighborhood/ common name of the location.

```
var subLocality: String! { get } // neighborhood, common name, eg. Mission District
```